# couldn't delete file.dll using python script

Tags: python, dll

I wrote a simple script to delete a few files from some directories, I have to delete all the .exe files and all the .dll files. I manage to delete the .exe files using `os.remove("path_name")` but when I am trying to delete the .dll files I get "Windows Error: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid". I am adding my code below and I hope someone can help me solve the problem.

`for name in dirs:
    dirPath = RES_PATH + "\\" + name
    dirsInside = os.listdir(dirPath)
    LOG_FILE = open(dirPath + "\\log.log", 'w')
    for doc in dirsInside:
        if (".exe" in doc):
            os.remove(dirPath + "\\" + doc)
        elif (".dll" in doc):
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(dirPath, doc))
        if ("ResultFile.txt" in doc):
            pathToResultFile = dirPath + "\\" + doc
            fileResult = open(pathToResultFile, 'r')
            lines = fileResult.readlines()`

thanks in advance.

## EDIT

when I am trying to use the `os.unlink()` I get:
"WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied"
for the .dll file (the .exe file is deleted as it should)

Comment: What does error #267 mean?

Comment: "Windows Error: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid" this is what it gives me.

Comment: Add that to your question. Then, create a minimal example in isolation, showing just two `unlink()` calls. The first one, deleting the exe, should succeed. The second one, deleting the DLL, should fail.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is **.dll** that you are trying to delete there is  a big chance that the file is in use, and therefore can't be deleted.

Try to see if you can delete it manually first.

Comment: thank you, but i can't delete it manually because there are many files that I need to delete. isn't there a better way?